# experimentalObjectRestSpread not working in ESLint

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, eslint

I'm trying to get ESLint to let me use object rest/spread. Despite my best efforts I keep getting this error:

**`[js] Property assignment expected.`**

when I hover over the elipses (`...`) with the red squiggly.

[image: alt]

My `.eslinstrc.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "extends": "airbnb",
    "plugins": [
        "react"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true
        }
    },
    "rules": {
        "no-console": 0
    }
}
```

I know for sure that the prefs are getting read, as the `no-console` rule, `react` plugin, and `airbnb` style guide is working as expected.

To enable object rest/spread, `experimentalObjectRestSpread` is the key here (haha), and [it seems to be working for other people](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/issues/788). However it refuses to work for me. I'm at a loss `\o/`

**Update: I'm using Visual Studio Code v1.2.1**

Comment: Are `const` declarations within a block scope? What is expected result of `...foo`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Am I right assuming you are using vscode? I think the error comes from vscode itself. Otherwise the error message would start with `[eslint]` instead of `[js]`.

It looks like vscode currently doesn't support object spread operators (see: [Issue on Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1974)).

You could disable JavaScript validation with the setting `{ "javascript.validate.enable": false }`.

Another alternative would be [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
const foo = {
  a: 1
};
const bar = 'bar';
const res = Object.assign(
    {},
    foo,
    {bar}
);
```

Comment: Aaaaaarg thanks for this :D It was driving me crazy, lol. Yeah I've been using Object.assign in the meantime, but it really sucks cuz a lot of React projects use object rest/spread :/ hopefully VSC gets support for it sometime soon!

Comment: Object spread operators are now supported! See: [Release notes Visual Studio Code V1.6](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_6)